# Mono certificate issue: Unsupported hash algorithm: 1.2.840.10045.4.3.3

Tags: mono, certificate

I'm running mono v3.2.8 in ubuntu 14.04 and it was working fine until after upgrading the OS. I got the error when running my NodeJS application (use edge.js to communicate with mono):

```
Error getting response stream (Write: The authentication or decryption has failed.): SendFailure
```

I thought it were the same old bug that could be solved by running the command:

```
$ mozroots --import --ask-remove
```

But it's not, I still got the error. I check everything I could until I saw this error:

```
$ certmgr -list -c -v Trust
...
X.509 v3 Certificate
  Serial Number: 2A99639B9E014C5450700062AAAF471F
  Issuer Name:   C=GB, S=Greater Manchester, L=Salford, O=COMODO CA Limited, CN=COMODO ECC Certification Authority
  Subject Name:  C=GB, S=Greater Manchester, L=Salford, O=COMODO CA Limited, CN=COMODO ECC Certification Authority
  Valid From:    3/6/2008 12:00:00 AM
  Valid Until:   1/18/2038 11:59:59 PM
  Unique Hash:
  Key Algorithm:        1.2.840.10045.2.1
  Algorithm Parameters: 06052B81040022
  Public Key:          /* some public key */
  Signature Algorithm:  1.2.840.10045.4.3.3
  Algorithm Parameters: None

Unhandled Exception:
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Unsupported hash algorithm: 1.2.840.10045.4.3.3
  at Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate.get_Signature () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Tools.CertificateManager.DisplayCertificate (Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate x509, Boolean machine, Boolean verbose) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Tools.CertificateManager.List (ObjectType type, Mono.Security.X509.X509Store store, Boolean machine, System.String file, Boolean verbose) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Tools.CertificateManager.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Unsupported hash algorithm: 1.2.840.10045.4.3.3
  at Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate.get_Signature () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Tools.CertificateManager.DisplayCertificate (Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate x509, Boolean machine, Boolean verbose) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Tools.CertificateManager.List (ObjectType type, Mono.Security.X509.X509Store store, Boolean machine, System.String file, Boolean verbose) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Tools.CertificateManager.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I thought maybe the these errors are related, but don't know how to solve this. Reinstalling mono doesn't help. Are there any possible solution? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: 3.2.8 is 18 months old - you may consider building/downloading a newer version for Ubuntu. It doesn't appear the Ubuntu package is current, however.